# How to edit website locally while live DB is still being edited

Tags: php, wordpress, local, development-environment

I'm relatively new to web development and I have some serious concerns about repairing/editing/fixing live site.

I use WordPress and its DB hold also configuration, so let's say that I need to do some work on website with e-shop. I will start website on my local with current version of DB from live website. But in few hours, when I'm done, I can't just overwrite live DB with my DB from local environment, because there are some new orders, posts etc.

How can we deal with this kinds of things?

Thanks everyone who will share his advice or experiences!

Comment: Can't comment of WP but Drupal has the Features module which does this sort of thing, not sure if there's something similar for Wordpress?

Comment: @james-geldart All over internet I read that merging two DBs is risky and nearly impossible, but there must be some way.

Comment: Yeah it's a nightmare, and it's a weakness of config-heavy CMS platforms even though the fact that you can do so much with config is their strength. What Features does for Drupal is allow you to package various changes (including content and config) up into a package that you can then place under version control. But like I say, I don't know if there's a WP equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First youhave to make note of all the changes you are making in the files. You have to document it properly.
Next there are actually three cases

i) When changing the files alone

if you are changing just the files then obviously no need to change the database only the files needs to be updated. First no need to hack the core wordpress files as everything can be done through "actions" and "filters" method. I mean by creating a plugin so your core files are safe. https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

ii) When chaning the database alone

if you are chaning the database instead of deleting the entire datase and reloading you can simply alter the tables using "ALTER" command http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html.

iii) Changing both databse and files.

Follow (i) and (ii)

Comment: In case of changing DB. what happens if I've created for example form with ID 5 on local and on live was also made form with ID 5? There must be collision while trying to use ALTER command .I assume what you suggested works only if I edit values that are already in DB, right?

Comment: @FrankMejzlik you should not overwrite the existing database. If your id is unique and auto incrementing then just insert another row with new id. So the existing id in live server remains as it is.

Comment: point (i) should be done with a version control system like Git or Subversion. Point (ii) is difficult because while you could in theory create an SQL script that you run against the database, in Wordpress (or other similar systems) you don't (or shouldn't) update the database directly, you do it through the UI and that doesn't track the DB changes you make. You could always enable query logging on your dev database though, that might work...

Comment: @james-geldart Thank you for reply! Yeah we have point (i) sorted out, we use gitlab for that and then push to live server via SSH, that's ok. Point (ii) is something I need to figure out soon :) I will try query logging you mentioned